# Unable to upload document in library in SharePoint 2013 using iPhone 6

Tags: document, file-upload, library

In SharePoint 2013 document library, I am unable to upload document using iPhone 6. File `Upload document` button is disabled and `Add New Document` button is not available in the Document Library.

Is file upload not supported using iPhone 6 or Is there any settings to enable it?

Comment: user may not have permissions to upload the file

Comment: Actually, logged in user is able to perform admin related tasks. So he has adequate permission to upload documents.

Answer (score 3):

Using a phone input device can be tricky. Either you use the mobile views where you see the libraries in a row or you switch to PC view using the more menu **. . .**

If I try to upload using the upload button I can’t hit the button even if it’s there. But if I go to the ribbon and upload from its Upload button, it works as expected. Try these three different options and see where this leads you.

[image]

Another option is to use the applications for iPhone such as Word, Excel, PowerPoint and OneNote for iPhone/iPad. Add your SharePoint location there and you’ll get an easier uploading and editing experience.

Just make sure that the user trying to upload have contribute permission level.